# Mermin-Wagner in Second Quantization

Tags: condensed-matter, hilbert-space, spin-models

The following [link](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Mermin-Wagner_Theorem) provides a detailed proof of the Mermin-Wagner Theorem for the quantum spin model. However, one thing that I don't quite understand is why the underlying Hilbert space $H_\Lambda$ of the lattice system $\Lambda$ is the tensor product of $N$ single-particle Hilbert spaces? Shouldn't it be the symmetrization/anti-symmetrization of the tensor product, i.e., the $N$-particle Fock space, depending on whether we have fermions or bosons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to symmetrize or antisymmetrize the tensor product of the spin spaces. Each spin is tied to a  particlular site in the lattice, so different spins are  *distinguishable*.

It would be different if the objects with spin were able to hop/tunnel  from site to site. Then their statistics would matter.